# Removing an application created by dragging a URL onto the unity bar?

Tags: unity, launcher

I accidentally dropped a YouTube url onto the Unity sidebar instead of dropping it into my text editor and it created a launch icon on the bar.

I deleted this icon from the bar but now when I right click .html files (I'm a web developer), I get the option to open the file with "Game of Thrones Season 4 - Backstage"

Any ideas how I get rid of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` for a `.desktop` file for "Game of Thrones Season 4 - Backstage" and remove it.